# Using given/when with IO::Select can_read

Tags: perl, switch-statement

I am concocting a DIY sleep study filter that will log events from input from an audio stream (2K bytes/sec), an accelerometer (10 readings/sec) and console terminal keystrokes.

I have put together this chunk of code:

```
$SELECT=IO::Select->new or die "muffed create SELECT: $!\n" ;

my $i ; foreach ($AREC,$IMU,$STDIN) {
        $i++ ;
        $SELECT->add($_) or die "muffed SELECT $i: $!\n" ;
}

while (TRUE) {
    foreach ($SELECT->can_read ) {
        given ($_) {
            when ($AREC)  {}# handle audio from pipe
            when ($IMU)   {}# handle acceleromter from UDP socket}
            when ($STDIN) {}# handle keystrokes }
        }
    }           
}
```

1. All of the given/when examples use string values or regular expressions. Will this work with filehandles?
2. I recall that slower devices should have greater priority to avoid getting drowned in the flood of data input from faster devices.  How should this be handled using IO::Select add and can_read?

I am using perl 5.30.0 on an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4):

Smart matching is *experimental* and considered a failure. It should be avoided!

```perl
while (1) {
   for ($SELECT->can_read ) {
      if    ( $_ == $AREC  ) { }
      elsif ( $_ == $IMU   ) { }
      elsif ( $_ == $STDIN ) { }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like dispatch tables for these sorts of things, using the expected values as hash keys and the subroutine to run as the hash values. Some Perl pseudocode:

```
my $subs = (
    SOME_AREC_VALUE  => sub { ... },
    SOME_IMU_VALUE   => sub { ... },
    SOME_STDIN_VALUE => sub { ... },
    );

$subs->{$_}->();
```

I write quite a bit about replacing syntax structure with data structure in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org) and [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com).

Comment: Your broke your answer in rev 3. The key needs to be (stringification of) the file handle returned by `can_read` (e.g. `$AREC`) /// I was going to include a dispatch table in my answer, but I didn't because the stringification of globs and references to globs and references to IOs are different so it could break. But when you posted your answer, I realized my solution also suffers from that "problem", and that it isn't really a problem since IO::Select always returns exactly what you pass to it.

Comment: Ah, I meant that as a pseudocode like snippet. The previous versions didn't work either because I was using input variables for keys, which is not what I meant.

Comment: I really like the look of your construct  `$subs->{$_}->();' for dispatch tables, however, I can't find it in Mastering Perl or Effective Perl Programming.  Can you point me where to find it?